# Inject HTML Where Script is Included

Tags: javascript

what I would like to do is this.  Wherever my script is included on the page, inject some html.  So wherever:

```
<script src="http://demo.com/stats/stats.js"></script>
```

Is added to the page, I can output

```
<div id="stats"></div>
```

At that position in the page.

Comment: What? When and how included; on load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overthink the problem:

```
document.write('<div id="stats"></div>');
```

This will fail however if the script is loaded asynchronously.

For a solution which works with asynchronously loaded scripts:

```
(function() {
  function addHtml() {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
      if (scripts[i].src !== 'http://demo.com/stats/stats.js') {
        continue;
      }
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.id = 'stats';
      if (scripts[i].nextElementSibling) {
        scripts[i].parentNode.insertBefore(div, scripts[i].nextElementSibling);
      } else {
        scripts[i].parentNode.appendChild(div);
      }
    }
  }
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    addHtml();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addHtml, false);
  }
})()
```

Comment: I don't really get it. What will it do, apart from just overwriting all your html?.. and where are you going to include...

Comment: `document.write` will NOT overwrite your document when used with a blocking script inline. It will do exactly what was requested.

Comment: @nicael [Writes a string of text to a document stream opened by document.open().

Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open which will clear the document.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) This means as long as the document is currently open (e.g. during initial page parse) and the script is executed synchronously (like it is by default) the script will just write it in wherever the tag is.

Comment: What if the script IS loaded aynch?